# Win32/GDI coloring a triangle

Tags: gdi, win32gui

I am making a series of triangles to represent a 3D shape using the vertices and the LineTo() and MoveTo() functions.

What is the best way to colour/fill these triangles?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN has a sample that draws shaded triangles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just use Polygon().

http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson12.htm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162814(v=vs.85).aspx

Use CreateSolidBrush() to create a brush, then use SelectObject() to install a brush into HDC.
Then you have the solid brush, call Polygon() with more than 3 vertices will let it draw a filled triangle for you.